# Changed idle behaviour (18.04, Lenovo X220)

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management

A recent update (I normally install all updates offered) seems to have changed the behaviour of my X220 laptop when left idle. Previously, with power/charger connected it would just keep running, even if I closed the lid. I like and want this behaviour.
Now, when left idle, the screen blanks after a time, and does not fully reactivate when the mouse pointer is moved or a key is pressed. Instead a blank (purple) screen appears, which I can't escape from except by using the system menu and choosing the only option which is available, namely to suspend. I can then immediately resume. This process is burdensome - takes a minute or so and I have to re-enter my password. I can't see what change (if any) has caused this.
Any suggestions where to look?